# About the Eigenvalues of submatrices of real symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Lets say I have a real symmetric matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$. I am considering sub-matrices $B$ of $A$. Lets say I have distinct indices $J=\{j\}$ with $1\leq j \leq N$. The sub-matrix $B$ is constructed by choosing those elements $A_{kl}$ with $k\in J$ and $l\in J$, while the corresponding elements in $B$ are ordered in the same way as they were in $A$. I now have two questions:

1. I think that if $A$ is positive definite then every sub-matrix I choose should be positive definite. Is that correct?
2. Decompose $A$ in two matrices $B$ and $C$. $B$ and $C$ are formed as described above through the index sets $J=\{j\}$ and $K=\{k\}$ with $1\leq k \leq N$ and $1\leq j \leq N$. $J$ and $K$ are disjunct. Lets say $C$ is positive definite and $B$ and only one negative eigenvalue in its spectrum. Can I say something about the eigenvalues of $A$?

I hope I explained the situation clearly and I appreciate your help.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: Your question is not clear what is the decomposition of $A$ to $B$ and $C$.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes you are right. I will adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

If $M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}A&b\\b^T&c\end{array}\right]$ is a symmetric real matrix of order $n+1$ and $A$ is of order $n$, then the eigenvalues $\mu_0\leq \ldots\leq \mu_n$ of $M$ and the eigenvalues $a_1\leq a_n$ of $A$ interlace, that means
$$\mu_0\leq a_1\leq \mu_1\ldots\leq a_n\leq \mu_n$$ A way to prove this is to apply the Schur factorization to the matrix $M-\lambda I_{n+1}$. It is reasonable to assume first that $A$ is invertible with distinct eigenvalues. The general case is done by density. Iterating this result answers to your questions.